# Recorrer y guardar datos Datagrid de Easyui

Tags: javascript

HOLA DISCULPEN COMO PUEDO GUARDAR LOS DATOS DE MI DATAGRID DE EASYUI, TENGO EL SIGUIENTE CODIGO

+

```
 var dg = $('#tb_planMejora');
    var rows = dg.datagrid('getRows');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        var registraCompromiso = 'http://localhost:5000/apis/rrh/registrarAspecto/' + rowPlan.id_persona + '/' +row; 
        $.ajax({
            url: registraCompromiso,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (respuesta) {
                
            },
            error: function (respuesta) {
                 console.log(respuesta);
         }
        });
        console.log("EL RESULTADO DE LA URL ES: ", registraCompromiso);
    }
    dg.datagrid('reload');
```

- Me devuelve el siguiente resultado en la consola, lo que necesito es guardar: hola soy una variable y hola soy otra variable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Lo que guardo en mi datagrid es lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado con poner dentro del bucle, debajo de la asignación de `var row =` esto?  `row[i] = "EL NOMBRE DE LA VARIABLES ES:" + row;` y despues, fuera del bucle, poner `dg.datagrid('reload');`?   Si te funciona avisa que crearé una respuesta acorde a eso.

Comment: hola, si lo probe pero no me funciono

Comment: Cuando dices guardar los datos... ¿te refieres en una base de datos? ¿o solo lo que estas viendo?  Si es en una base de datos deberias pasarle un ajax hacia un php para que lo actualizara y luego recargar el datagrid  seguramente.

Comment: Si necesito todo lo que escriba en el datagrid, no pase completo el codigo pero en si esto es lo que estaba probando

Comment: ya actualice el codigo,en si necesito guardar en una variable dentro del ciclo todo lo que vaya guardando y pasarle esa variable a la url

Comment: te falta pasarle el `data` al ajax, sino no creo que haga nada (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), a menos que con un GET sea suficiente, en cuyo caso cambialo por GET

Comment: bien lo guardo pero me refiero que aqui en la url 'http://localhost:5000/apis/rrh/registrarAspecto/' + rowPlan.id_persona + '/' +row; , yo paso un id eso esta bien, pero necesito pasarle una variable que me contenga lo que se haya registrado en el datagrid, en este caso es row, o sea recorrer todos los rows del datagrid y guardar el contenido de cada row en una variable y esa variable pasarsela a la url

Comment: Lo que tengas que pasar (la verdad es que no te he entendido bien aun) lo tendras que hacer en formato json y usando el parametro `data:` en el `$.ajax` y luego procesarlo en el php adecuadamente...  Si lo que quieres pasar es un objeto de javascript con valores dentro entonces usa `data:JSON.stringify(objeto)`  y por POST

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, no había visto bien que lo que me devolvía era un objeto, entonces tuve que acceder a la propiedad de ese objeto.

Comment: Pues ponlo aquí.  Así lo veremos todos. Esto que has puesto parece más un comentario que una respuesta con la resolucion de tu problema

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).